# coffeescript image change on thumbnail hover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, coffeescript

I have a product page, http://pants.telegraphbranding.com/t/women/long-sleeve, and when you hover over the thumbnails below the main image, the main image should switch to the thumbnail. But it's not and I'm not sure why.

I'm using html data elements with a ruby method to assign product id's to each product:

```
<div class="main-image" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
```

Here's my coffeescript:

```
add_image_handlers = ->

 thumbnails = ($ '.product-images ul.thumbnails')
 ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumb', 'productid', $(this).find('img')
 thumbnails.find('li').eq(0).addClass 'selected'
 thumbnails.find('a').on 'click', (event) ->
  ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumb', ($ event.currentTarget).attr('href')
  ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumbId', ($ event.currentTarget).parent().attr('id')
  ($ this).mouseout ->
     thumbnails.find('li').removeClass 'selected'
     ($ event.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass 'selected'
  false
thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseenter', (event) ->
  $(this).find('img').attr 'src', ($ event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href')

thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseleave', (event) ->
  $(this).find('img').attr 'src', ($ '.main-image').data('selectedThumb')
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you mouseover the `<li>` elements, the src attribute of your  is set to "productid".

Well... maybe something more concise would suffice?

```
$('.product-images ul.thumbnails li').hover(function() {
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(this).closest('.product').find('.main-image a img').attr('src', href);
}, function() {});
```

In coffee:

```
$(".product-images ul.thumbnails li").hover (->
  href = $(this).find("a").attr("href")
  $(this).closest(".product").find(".main-image a img").attr "src", href
), ->
```

I leave to you the choice of the images sources. Remove your code before the testing.